# Windows Timezone and their abbreviations?

Tags: timezone

I want to know the abbreviations for the TIME ZONES that are available in the Windows OS....(i.e) i need abbreviations for the time zones that are listed in the windows DATE AND TIME PROPERTIES?

Can anybody provide some link where i can get the abbreviations for the time zones.

Comment: You read this?  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/3aa4420a-a5bf-48a3-af13-17a0905ce366/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get any abbreviations in the Date and Time control panel applet on my current system, but it sounds like you're after a list like [the one on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations), which lists many of the abbreviations, as well as information like name, and UTC offset.

I don't believe these abbreviations are held within the operating system (after all, there is no one to one mapping), so these wouldn't be available programmatically beyond building your own look up.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not a true one-to-one mapping. To list the actual time zones available, you need to use ***tzutil*** utility provided on Windows.

Example below will save the full list of values to a file:

```
tzutil /l > C:/list_of_all_timezones.txt
```

Note that this will give you a listing for that particular version of Windows. Different releases as well as different language versions will yield different results.

Comment: And, sadly, **tzutil** does not list abbreviations, but merely what is stored in the registry.